# Three-dimensional vectors and force systems

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, 3d, vector-analysis

Full disclosure: this is a homework problem. However, I find myself stuck in the middle. The problem is below

> As shown, a system of cables suspends a crate weighing W = 350 . 
>   (Part C 1 figure)  The dimensions in the figure are as follows:  h=
>   22.2 , l = 4.20 , x = 9.50 , theta = 40.0, and phi = 16.0. Determine TA, TD, and TE, the tensions in cable segments CA, CD, and CE,
>   respectively.

I already found that TA = 406, i still need to find TD and TE. I know that CE = CF and that I need to find TD and TE through the Z forces and that the Y forces in these two should equate but I'm not sure about that either.

A push in the right direction would be a huge help.

Comment: Do add figures, we don't even know about T, A, B, and _blahblahs_.

Comment: With many forces and tensions playing a role are you sure this wouldn't be better received on a physics forum? Do add the figure. Kinda pointless otherwise :-)

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestions, I'm new to math.stackexchange. Apparently I need 10 rep to post an image, but here is a link in case someone can edit. http://i.imgur.com/Q6foU.jpg

Comment: Also, I wasn't aware of the Physics.StackExchange site. Can someone with rights move my question over, or should I crosspost?